# size of program in ROM

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, stm32f4

I am newbie. I want to copy my full program from ROM to RAM using DMA operation. But how can I calculate the size of my program?

Comment: You mean the program that you download to your MCU? I mean here the .hex or .elf, etc. files.

Comment: arm-whatever-objcopy -O binary input.elf output.bin and then look at the .bin file size.

Comment: ram is generally smaller than rom, so you could just copy a ram sized amount over.  leaving room for the stack if you are using a stack to do that copy.

Comment: that means every time my binary file size changes I have to manually edit my code to setup DMA operation?

Comment: you can leave markers in the binary, you can simply use the linker script as most folks do so the toolchain computes the size, a laundry list of solutions.  just pick one.

Answer (score 1):

my general solution for this is, since you want/need to link for the target memory, sram, you do that and compile a binary, and convert from elf,ihex,whatever to a raw binary.  Then you can have a program (host side) that reads that binary and makes it say for example a header file of raw data including a define for the size.   You create another program (target) that is the bootloader, which runs on the flash, knows how to dma, and the header file is included so that it shows up as .rodata (hint use a const in the declaration).   The make system at that point using your bin to c header program does all the work.

Comment: My program simply uses 4 or 8 register ldm/stm and is in asm not dma, but you wanted dma for some reason.